# Getting 302 status code when I want to add selected product to order in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1

I'm getting the 302 status code in the firebug:

```
Request URL:http://myproject.local/index.php/adminpanel/sales_order_create/loadBlock/block/search,items,shipping_method,totals,giftmessage,billing_method?isAjax=true
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I add an item to the order -> select payment method-> select shipping method-> add a new item to the order and when I press the add selected product to order I'm getting 302.

This is the function, which I'm thinking responsible for this:

```
 public function loadBlockAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        try {
            $this->_initSession()
                ->_processData();
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e){
            $this->_reloadQuote();
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            $this->_reloadQuote();
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $e->getMessage());
        }


        $asJson= $request->getParam('json');
        $block = $request->getParam('block');

        $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        if ($asJson) {
            $update->addHandle('adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_json');
        } else {
            $update->addHandle('adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_plain');
        }

        if ($block) {
            $blocks = explode(',', $block);
            if ($asJson && !in_array('message', $blocks)) {
                $blocks[] = 'message';
            }

            foreach ($blocks as $block) {
                $update->addHandle('adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_' . $block);
            }
        }
        $this->loadLayoutUpdates()->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();
        $result = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->toHtml();
        if ($request->getParam('as_js_varname')) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setUpdateResult($result);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/showUpdateResult');
        } else {
            $this->getResponse()->setBody($result);
        }
    }
```

The ajax loader is getting frozen and If I don't close my browser, it will crash :)  Probably a memory issue, but I can't figure it out. Any help to debug this ?

Thank you

Comment: I am Facing same issue with magento 1.9.1. Do you have solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out one solution. i am not sure what its drawback but its working for me.

put following code in .htaccess file

> Header always unset X-Frame-Options

you can also try this

> Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN